# What's the ruby syntax headers "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" => "x-requested-with"?

Tags: ruby

I think it's pass a hash to the headers method,

But I don't know why

```
headers {"Access-Control-Allow-Headers" => "x-requested-with"}
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid ambiguity with a block, that form is not allowed. You have to do either of the following:

```
headers({"Access-Control-Allow-Headers" => "x-requested-with"})
```

or

```
headers("Access-Control-Allow-Headers" => "x-requested-with")
```